# how to update Highcharts legends when series change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

Highcharts config object:

```
const config = (series) => {
  chart: {...},
  legend: {
    enabled: true,
    itemStyle: {...},  
  },
  series,
}
```

The series gets updated every time the state object in the parent component changed. this config gets also updated, but not the legend. If I deselect one of the legends and update the state, the legend keeps deselected.

How can I update the legends every time a series change?

Comment: refer https://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic check whether JSON series keys are getting updated

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue with the sample data on some online editor?